# OSgeolive with geonetwork 2.10

Tags: geonetwork, osgeo-live

I need to make a training on geonetwork 2.10.
OSGeolive is a good option for me, as I would not have to worry about the installation.

The current version, Osgeolive 9.5, has geonetwork 3.0 which interface is way too different from geonetwork 2.10.
Which version of OSgeolive could I donwload to have geonetwork 2.10?

Answer (score 1):

You need to download OsGeolive 9.0.

Blog with changes: [9.5 changes](http://cameronshorter.blogspot.si/2016/03/osgeo-live-95-call-for-translators-and.html)

> The following applications have been updated:
>   geonetwork 2.10.4 -> 3.0.3

Download from here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/osgeo-live/files/